# Using dynamic keys on object with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function like this

```
interface Cat {
    color: string,
    weight: number,
    cute: Boolean, // eventhough all cats are cute!
}

export const doSomething = (
    cat: Array<Cat| null>,
    index: number,
    key:  keyof typeof cat,
    payload: string | number | Boolean
) => {
    ....
    cat[key] = payload
    ....
}
```

This gives me

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Which I understand is because TypeScript thinks that `key` can be any string instead one of `"color", "weight", "cute"`.
How would I tell in the function declaration that `key` is one of the three (`"color", "weight", "cute"`)?

I tried

```
...
key:  keyof Cat,
...
```

Without luck. This

```
 cat[key] = payload
```

Gives me now

> Type 'string| number | Boolean | ' is not assignable to type '(string & number & Boolean )

Comment: But `cat` is an array of `Cat` elements. So its *keys* are array indices, and thus integers.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I know. Is there a way to tell TypeScript that the `string` passed to `key` must be one of the `keys` (`"color", "weight", "cute"`) defined in `Cat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat` is an array so `keyof typeof cat` are the keys of the array not the `Cat` interface. For those you can use `keyof Cat`

```
export const doSomething = (
    cat: Array<Cat | null>,
    index: number,
    key: keyof Cat,
    payload: string | number | Boolean
) => {
    cat.forEach(c => {
        if (c) {
            c[key] = payload
        }
    });
}
```

This still doesn't quite work, because there is no correlation between `key` and `payload` you could call `doSomething(.., ..., 'cute', 1)`.

You need to add a generic type parameter to tie the payload to the key:

```
export const doSomething = <K extends keyof Cat>(
    cat: Array<Cat | null>,
    index: number,
    key: K,
    payload: Cat[K]
) => {
    let c = cat[index];
    if (c) {
        c[key] = payload
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzMg3gWAFDKHIID2ANiVAFzIDOYUoA5gDT5HIDuEwTAFmBogArgFsARtDYEiCYZBriS5CHBAtkAek3IIANwjg+JYf2RwyZYhlrmoKOZACE+AL758EAB4AHSplIQemQAExIAZRJRCDA+ZmQAXmQAHgBpXS9IEBDbAGsIAE8SGDQMAD4ACnZZDBoAQSgoOALk9EwAH2QRSzLpDlAQ7yExSSg+onyCmlTxwh9mijgQmjaAbVSAXXwASkSy7GrCMhjiROswVYHvDYBuQ+RgEoqEXdwZDkIEVcmNs-mCxYhe7uPAg-BhSLRWLMCqrDYaAAMGgARI4IMiNAxhBBtkA)

The `K` in the code above is called a generic type parameter. A function can have generic type parameters in order to capture extra information from the call site making it a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content). `K extends keyof Cat` means that `K` must be a subtype of `keyof Cat` so it could be one of `"color"`, `"weight"`, `"cute"`.

So when we call `doSomething([], 0, "cute", true)`, `K` will be `"cute"`. Since we now have the information about which key the function was called with, we can use it  in a [type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content) (`Cat[K]`) to get the actual type of the property with key `"cute"`.

Comment: I understand. Could you explain what this line `<K extends keyof Cat>` does? I understand what `keyof Cat` means, but not in cunjunction with `extends`, `<>` and before the `()`.

Comment: @four-eyes added more explanations